# Find the surface of least area spanned by a given contour

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

I'm reading a book on Calculus of Variations, and am confused by the following problem:

> Find the surface of least area spanned by a given contour.

The answer is to write a functional of the form:

$$J [z] = \iint_R \sqrt {1+z_x^2+z_y^2} dx dy $$

Now, use Euler's equation:

$$F_z-\frac {\partial}{\partial x}
F_{z_x}-\frac {\partial}{\partial y} F_{z_y} = 0$$

Where $F = \sqrt {1+z_x^2+z_y^2} $

The calculation does not confuse me so much as *what* we are actually finding.

I can see that the argument of the integral is highly analogous to arclength. When finding the curve of least length that connects two points, we apply the single variable Euler equation to:
$$\int_L \sqrt{1+y'^2}dx $$

However, I'm not entirely sure where the formula for $J [z] $ comes from, nor what it means for a surface to be spanned by a contour (in fact, I'm not all that certain of what a contour is)

I am enjoying the book, but I have definitely been ambitious to try and tackle this subject, as it seems to take a number of subjects I am only vaguely familiar with for granted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation of your question suggests (i.e., is consistent with) the following interpretation:

- $R$ denotes a bounded plane region whose boundary consists of one or more simple closed curves.
- A *contour* (blue) is a space curve obtained as the graph of a smooth, real-valued function $u$ over the boundary of $R$.
- A *surface spanning a contour* (shaded) is the graph of a smooth, real-valued function $z$ in $R$ whose values agree with $u$ on the boundary of $R$.

The functional $J$ is the surface area for the graph of $f$; by seeking critical points of $J$, you're finding surfaces of a particular type (namely, graphs) whose area is critical among all surfaces spanning the given contour (wireframe).

[image: Surfaces spanning a contour]

Comment: It seems from the question that we're working in $\mathbb {R}^3$, so is this to say that we're looking for a curve in $\mathbb {R}^3$ whose surface area is minimized when under the constraint that it overlaps (for lack of a better word) some perimeter in $\mathbb {R}^2$ (the contour)?

Comment: In other words, an analogy would be that the contour is some closed shape drawn on the ground, and the surface is the elevation of the ground at each point within the contour. Is this the correct idea?

Comment: @infinitylord: No, the “unknown“ is the function $z(x,y)$; its graph over the region $R$ is the minimal surface.  The contour is probably not drawn on the ground, otherwise the surface would be flat.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: It was an elementary analogy, but ground is not always flat. If you draw a very large closed shape on the ground in a hilly area, I think the analogy would work (if it doesn't, please elaborate). And as you're saying, we're not actually finding the curve in $\mathbb {R}^3$ itself, but rather the function generating it's surface (I see very little difference between the two)?

Comment: The contour (a space curve) is given (fixed at the outset). The _spanning surface_ (function whose graph "fills in" the contour and has critical area) is sought. Even if the curve is drawn on non-flat ground, the critical-area surface need not be the surface of the ground itself.

Comment: @infinitylord: Ah, I get your point now of the ground not always being flat.  Yes, you can think of the curve being a trail in the woods, and the surface the expanse of terrain enclosed by that trail.  The curve/trail are one-dimensional, whereas the surface/terrain are two-dimensional.  The graph of a function of two variables over a plane region (as $R$ is) is a surface, not a curve.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: thank you for the clarification, I believe I understand what a contour is now (it was largely terminology that befuddled me).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: The surface must fill in the contour? So if the contour were a circle, the surface would necessary have to fill in the area of the circle? It was my belief that the surface only needs to connects at the boundary, and can do (more or less) whatever it likes outside of that (that is to say, the surface would not need to be contained within the plane that the circle is drawn on)

Comment: 1. The surface must fill the contour in the sense that the contour must be the boundary of the surface. 2. If the contour happens to be planar, the only critical spanning surface is the plane region bounded by the contour. (In this case, $z_{x} = z_{y} = 0$, and $J$ achieves its _a priori_ minimum value.) That said, even if the contour is planar, the _family of surfaces_ among which you search includes non-planar surfaces. (In case it matters, the shaded saddle surface in the diagram is not the critical surface for the blue contour, though it's qualitatively close.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: thank you, that was helpful. I suppose my problem is how to define a 'boundary'. As I currently understand, if, for example, the contour were a circle, the surface could be a cone whose base matches this circle. Why wouldn't the sides of the cone up to the point be considered a boundary?

Comment: You're right that a circle could also be the boundary of a cone. (The cone would not, however, be the graph of a _smooth_ function, so would not be "eligible for consideration" as a critical-area surface, and again, a non-planar surface bounded by a planar loop (even if it were smooth) would not be a critical point of area for a planar loop.)

Comment: The physical set-up to think of is: A loop of wire $C$ projecting to a simple closed plane curve is a _contour_, and a soap film spanning $C$ is a critical point of $J$.

Answer (score 2):

This the classical Plateau's problem of minimal surfaces where mean curvature vanishes. Solutions are due to

[Radó, René and Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau%27s_problem)

It is visualized physically by soap films spanning the given boundary. Finding coordinates of a skew quadrilateral 3D closed contour or loop (where x,y,z are functions of a single parameter that could be arc,) involves hyperelliptic integrals.

Answer (score 2):

Setting
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\delta\iint_R\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\iint_R\frac{z_x\delta z_x+z_y  \delta z_y}{\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=-\iint_R\delta z\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{z_x}{\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&-\iint_R\delta z\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{z_y}{\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=-\iint_R\delta z\frac{z_{xx}\left(1+z_x^2+z_y^2\right)}{\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}^3}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&+\iint_R\delta z\frac{z_x^2z_{xx}+z_xz_yz_{xy}}{\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}^3}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&-\iint_R\delta z\frac{z_{yy}\left(1+z_x^2+z_y^2\right)}{\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}^3}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&+\iint_R\delta z\frac{z_y^2z_{yy}+z_xz_yz_{xy}}{\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}^3}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=-\iint_R\delta z\frac{z_{xx}\left(1+z_y^2\right)+z_{yy}\left(1+z_x^2\right)-2z_xz_yz_{xy}}{\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}^3}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
\end{align}
$$
for all $\delta z$, requires
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{z_{xx}\left(1+z_y^2\right)+z_{yy}\left(1+z_x^2\right)-2z_xz_yz_{xy}=0}
$$
which is true when a surface has zero [Mean Curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_curvature#Surfaces_in_3D_space).

Comment: I have never studied differential geometry or topology, so I am pretty unfamiliar with mean curvature. Does this mean that, as an analogy, if we took a coin and bent and stretched it into some curved shape, and took the coin's boundary to be the contour, the minimum-area surface would be the surface of the coin (so that it perfectly follows the curvature of the boundary)?

Comment: Instead take a flexible copper/ aluminum loop and after removing it from a soap solution observe it  spanning across the boundary as a beautiful minimal film.Directions of zero normal curvature form a net and are  always orthogonal  If you take a flat coin of sufficiently ductile material and beat it up to stretch boundary parts  so that the edge lengths increase ( or radial parts shrink) it develops saddle points (example Pringles chip) all over. The problem of boundary differential element expansion forming  mean curvature $H=0$ imho has never been  solved.

Comment: @infinitylord: when a plane containing the normal to a surface cuts that surface, the curvature of the intersection varies with the direction of the normal to the plane. The minimum and maximum section curvatures occur when the normals to the plane are perpendicular to each other.  The mean curvature of the surface is the average of the maximum and minimum section curvatures.  The section curvature can be positive or negative depending on whether the intersection curves in the direction of the normal to the surface or in the direction opposite of the normal to the surface.