# Does a surface with given boundary in $\mathbb{R}^3$ exist?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

Given a (smooth) simple closed curve $C \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, is there a (smooth) surface $S$ with $\partial S = C$? I'm aware there is a [variational problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337413/find-the-surface-of-least-area-spanned-by-a-given-contour) to find among such surfaces the one with minimal area. Here I'm interested in the statement and proof of some existence theorem. Some cases where the existence is clear: if $C$ is planar, and more generally if $C$ is the curve of intersection of a a graph and a cylinder, $x_1=g(x_2,x_3)$ and $f(x_2,x_3)=0$

(This question came up when I read in a calculus book that $\text{curl }\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{0}$ implies $\mathbf{F}=\nabla f$ for some scalar function $f(x,y,z)$. The proof was: $\mathbf{F}=\nabla f$ iff $\mathbf{F}$ is conservative; to show $\mathbf{F}$ is conservative, consider $\int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$ for any closed curve $C$. "THERE IS" a surface $S$ with $C$ as its boundary. By stokes theorem, and the fact that $\text{curl }\mathbf{F}=0$, $\int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r} = 0$. So, my question is why this surface even exists.)

Comment: Yes. These are called Seifert surfaces.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I clarified my question in a comment below. Thanks for referring me to Seifert surfaces. I can say my question is about a step in the algorithm that is taken for granted.

Comment: One idea I had was: under some conditions on the curve $C$, there is a point $P$ far away enough that the segments $(PX]$ for $X\in C$ are all disjoint. So we call this cone $S$, smooth out the vertex, and get a surface that way.

Answer (score 4):

As already stated  by Cheerful Parsnip, such surfaces exist.

In fact, you can choose them to be compact and oriented (then they are Seifert surfaces). You can find an elementar proof in [Saveliev - Lectures on the Topology of 3-Manifolds].

If you know a little bit more machinery from differential topology, [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/118568) (much sexier) argument will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking at the algorithm and see that it does a lot more than what I had in mind (I was only imagining unknots). The algorithm's early steps involve 'attaching disks' - the existence of this attachment is I guess what I'm asking about. Shouldn't there be an easy analytic proof of existence of an attached disk under some smoothness/"injectivity-type" conditions on the curve?